# Nested commands in bash

Tags: bash, command, nested

I have been trying to truncate a filename, both at start and end.
I could achieve this with the following code:

```
#!bin/bash

FILENAME="hello123.txt"
NAME=${FILENAME%.t*}
NUMBER=${NAME:5}

DOESNTWORK=${${FILENAME%.t*}:5}

echo "$FILENAME"
echo "$NAME"
echo "$NUMBER"
echo "$DOESNTWORK"
```

My issue is with the **DOESNTWORK** line.
I get this error for the line: **main.sh: line 7: ${"${FILENAME%.t*}":5}: bad substitution**

Can someone please point out the mistake in the line?

Thanks,

Comment: The mistake is that bash doesn't support nested substitutions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Is there a way I can do what I was trying to do with a single line command?

Comment: You can if you use zsh!

Comment: `tr -dc '[:digit:]' <<< "${FILENAME}"`? `echo "${FILENAME//[^0-9]/}`? `echo "${FILENAME:5:3}"`?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use GNU grep why not use below:

```
DOESNTWORK=$(grep -o -E '[[:digit:]]+' <<< "$FILENAME")
```

Or with sed:

```
DOESNTWORK=$(sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' <<< "$FILENAME")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two ways to accomplish this in `bash`, at least for your specifically cited example. The first removes all characters that are not digits:

```
echo "${FILENAME//[^0-9]/}"
```

The second is by requesting a specific substring, which you were already partially using:

```
echo "${FILENAME:5:3}"
```

Which if these is most useful to you depends on how your actual use case compares to the example you cited...